# copy files after successful build

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, build-process

I'm working on a application where multiple dev will check-in everyday. I want to copy latest files only after check-in and successful TFS build to a share location. Currently I'm using post build script something like

Attrib -r "$(ProjectDir)Data*.*" /S & xcopy  /S /Y /I  "$(ProjectDir)Data*.*" "ShareLocation"

But the biggest problem is, even someone locally made some changes and then do local build, all files get copied to the shared location. But I only want to copy files which are checked-in and after successful TFS build.

Could someone please help what will be the best solution for this. I'm not a build engineer and know very less about MSBuild, so if your answer is MSBuild then please share some good sample rather than giving MSDN link. Thnks in advance.

Pritam

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dedicated server for TFS build then you can call a separate .bat file as post build event.

Inside the post build event you can specify the servername i.e. make a check whether build is done on that remote server. If build is on remote server you can have the copy command here.

Example : IF /i "%COMPUTERNAME%" == "servername" (command)

Comment: I update my default TFSBuild.Proj file with a target. So this way whenever someone checked-in something, then only it get copied to my server. but thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition that only release builds will execute the command:

if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" (command)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. Here is what I used in my TFSBuild.proj file and solve my problem

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
<Exec Command="Attrib -r &quot;$(SolutionRoot)\<SolutionFolder>\*.*&quot; /S"></Exec>
<Exec Command="xcopy /S /Y /I &quot;$(SolutionRoot)\<SolutionFolder>\*.*&quot; &quot;<server location>;" />
```